# How to improve enum identified struct for method overload in C#

Tags: c#, enums, overriding

I have a struct, that serves as a container for animation and sound.

```
    public struct BambooSounds{
    public Bamboo type;
    public AudioClip sound;
    public string animation;
}
```

Bamboo in this case is an enum by which I can identify an entry in an array of BambooSounds.

These are the methods heads to get the corresponding animations and sounds

```
public string BambooAnimation(Bamboo animation)
public AudioClip BambooSound(Bamboo sound)
```

The problem is i need to reimplement those methods for every new enum because i cannot override the methods, but the pattern how I use them doesn't change (struct, array of that struct, methods to return content of array structs).

How can I improve this so I have type safety and the easy usability and need to implement the logic only once. Tried with generic methods, but I got stuck at the point, where the generic parameter needed to be converted into the concrete type so I can compare it's value with the struct entry.

P.S.: I definitely want to keep either the struct, or instead a class, because in Unity those are shown in the inspector and can be configured without coding.

Comment: When you say "for every new enum", do you mean that you need to support any enumeration type? I mean, you've `BamboAnimation(SomeEnum animation)`?

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer Answer from Kram gets it very well

Comment: @Backs Yes, it's not called Unity3D anymore.

Comment: @AlexanderSeeck I was going to answer the same when I decided to drop it. After all, it's a bad design. There's no actual benefit of using generics if you can't specify it (class, paramterless constructor, derived X, implements I....)

Comment: @AlexanderSeeck Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question right, you want to build one function that can get all enums types.
So for an example we have two enums:

```
public enum Enum1
{
    Test
}
public enum Enum2
{
    Test2
}
```

This is the generic function:

```
static void TestEnum<T>(T enumType) where T : struct
        {
            if (enumType is Enum1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enum1");
            }
            if (enumType is Enum2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enum2");
            }
        }
```

And here how you can call it:

```
TestEnum<Enum1>(Enum1.Test);
TestEnum<Enum2>(Enum2.Test2);
```

Comment: Exactly like that and in addition Iwant to compare it to a value of the concrete type like so:

`enumType as Enum1 == Enum1.Test`

or something like that... don't know how that can be done

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions I'd pick between here:

1. Just hand-code all the methods.
2. Test type within a generic method, as per @Kram's answer.
3. Use a T4 template.

The first is obviously a nuisance. It does though come out with the correct results in the end, so depending on the number of `enum` parameters possible, I might just deal with it (possibly using some sort of script the first time I came to code it).

The second has the disadvantage of not giving full compile-time type safety, but it would work, and work reasonably performantly. It does still contain a lot of manual repetition.

A T4 template could be easy enough:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".gen.cs" #>
using System;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
  public partial struct BambooSounds
  {
  <#foreach(var type in new []{"Bamboo", "Wood", "Metal", "Whatever"};){#>
    public string <#=type#>Animation(<#=type#> animation)
    {
      // Implementation
    }
    public AudioClip <#=type#>Sound(<#=type#> sound)
    {
      // Implementation
    }
    public void ThisMethodOverloadsToShowThatCanBeDoneToo(<#=type#> thing)
    {
      // Implementation
    }
  <#}#>
  }
}
```

Having the `struct` as `partial` means you can have most of the definition in a normal .cs file, which tends to be a lot easier to work with, and have the T4 only generate the code you need it to deal with.

While T4 isn't as nice to work with as normal code (poorer IDE support), one can produce a large number of overloads very quickly.

Comment: I opted to drop my answer, not because I feel that it can't be useful. I'm convinced that not only your approach but also Karm isn't the way to go. It seems like there's some design issue and it could be solved using interfaces, btw, sadly, I don't have time now to compose these kind of answers...

Comment: Would be nice though, if the design has flaws, how I would go about getting it working a different way. What would you use as a unique and readable identifier so you know which struct to pick from an array of them?